# Branch.io redirect only after user login

Tags: ios, xcode, branch.io

I am using branch to redirect the user to a particular view of my app after clicking an invitation link. It works except that I need them to redirect only AFTER they login, not before like I have now. 
From what I can tell no methods on my initial view controller gets called after clicking a branch link and all the setup has to be done on AppDelegate.
Here is some of the relevant code on my AppDelegate:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool  {
    Branch.getInstance().initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions, andRegisterDeepLinkHandler: { params, error in
        guard error == nil else { return }
        guard let userDidClick = params["+clicked_branch_link"] as? Bool else { return }
        if userDidClick {
            let branch = Branch.getInstance()
            branch?.initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions, andRegisterDeepLinkHandler: { params, error in
                if error == nil {
                    var controller = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController")

                    branch?.registerDeepLinkController(controller, forKey: "valid_link")
                    branch?.initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions, automaticallyDisplayDeepLinkController: true)

                    print("prm: \(params)")
                }
            })        }
    })
...
```

That redirects to DetailViewController like it's supposed to but I need it to redirect only AFTER they login.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Alex from Branch here: this is absolutely possible. You're currently using our [automatic routing implementation](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/advanced/ios/#register-view-controller-for-deep-link-routing), which simplifies things but isn't nuanced enough to handle this use case. Instead, you'll want to build a [custom link routing method](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/guide/ios/#building-a-custom-deep-link-routing-method) to store your link data until after the login process is completed.

**Edit:** generic implementation:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let branch: Branch = Branch.getInstance()
        branch.initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions, andRegisterDeepLinkHandler: {params, error in

        // If the key 'valid_link' is present in the deep link dictionary
        if error == nil && params["+clicked_branch_link"] != nil && params["valid_link"] != nil {

            // assign valid_link to a variable

        }
    return true
}

// perform your login process, and pass the valid_link variable through to the post-login viewcontroller for display
```

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer with any sample or explanation.

Comment: Without full details of the OP's authentication flow, no. See the updated answer for a generic approach

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, can you please help me in code for viewController also post login, means what to do there.

Comment: That's entirely up to you and how you've architected your app. As long as you have the link data inside a variable, you can use it however and whenever you want.